# Exchange 2010 Recipient Policy (username@example.com)

Tags: exchange-2010

I would like to set up a recipient policy that provides both `alias@` and `username@`:

```
======================================
alias@example.com    || %m@example.com
username@example.com || ?
======================================
```

I cannot seem to find any information about getting `username@example.com` into the policy. Does anyone know if this is possible to do?

Comment: Is it safe to assume your user names don't follow a standard that allows you to use one of the "first name"/"last name" formats?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I would like to change this but upper management are resisting and the current scheme works.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it through the Microsoft console, you can see the difference when creating the rule under Organization / Hub Transport / Email address policies.

Answer (score 0):

Alias *is* the username (SAMAccountName to be specific), but I'm unclear what you're calling the username in this case. Is that the display-name? The list of short-cuts is here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232171.aspx

%m is the name under "account" on the AD object
%d is the display-name, which might include spaces
%g.%s is the fairly normal FirstName.LastName@example.com formulation

Comment: This is incorrect (at least with 2010 it is). Alias is the alias set on the Mailbox at time of creation and is not the sAMAccountName).

Comment: True, but the default is sAMAccountName. We never change it, so I slipped my mind on that one.

Comment: Unfortunatly I need to use both values individually and would like to be able to use Recipient policies rather then manually adding email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't implemented 2010 yet but in our 2007 server I can just add an incoming smtp address to the mailbox account.  If you email either address it goes to the same mailbox.